# Tomcat 9 service using older version of java

Tags: java, tomcat, java-11, tomcat9

I am using Tomcat 9 and Java 11 on my windows server.

In my system there are total 3 JDKs present (two Java 1.8.x and one JDK 11 )

JAVA_HOME environment varibable points to JDK11
Also registry keys current version points to JDK11

I cannot uninstall older version of java 1.8 from my system as some of the apps are still using java 8.

Now when I am running Tomcat 9 service , it is picking older version of Java 1.8.x & not Java 11.

In catalina.bat file I have also added following explicitly

```
set JAVA_HOME=D:\Java\jdk 11.0.8
```

But still it picks older version of java. In the tomcat configuration java tab also points to Java 11 dll file.

When I run the tomcat locally using startup.bat file & not start the service through services app then in catalina logs I get correct version of Java.

Please suggest why tomcat service is not picking latest java 11 version.

Comment: In Tomcat Monitor's (Prunmgr) Java tab, do you have _"Use default"_ checked or unchecked?

Comment: Hi @Piotr , the check box in the Tomcat Monitor's Java tab is un checked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling your Tomcat service and installing it again using `service.bat` in tomcat folder.

```
service.bat remove
service.bat install
```

If that doesn't work ,check the appropriate registry key. Here is mine:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7.55\Parameters\Java

change the Jvm key value .

> Note :To open regedit ,
> In the search box on the taskbar, type regedit, then select Registry Editor (Desktop app) from the results.
> Right-click Start , then select Run. Type regedit in the Open: box, and then select OK.

Comment: Glad it helped . Please upvote my answer.